# Could Spring MVC call @ModelAttribute after @RequestMapping?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, modelattribute

I have a controller like this:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String update(@RequestParam("user") User user, ModelMap model){
        SaveUserToDatabase(user);
        return "index";
    }

    @ModelAttribute("user")
    String getUser() {
        return LoadCurrentUserFromDataBase();
    }
}
```

In short, my views would render `user` in almost **every** actions in `HomeController`,
but I don't want to code:

```
model.addAttribute("user", LoadCurrentUserFromDataBase())
```

in every actions, instead I'm seeking a way like `@ModelAttribute` to expose `user` to all my views.

However, according to the docs, `@ModelAttribute` methods in a controller are invoked **before** `@RequestMapping` methods, within the same controller.

As to my code, `getUser` is called before `update`, but i'd like to get the updated user.

Is there a way to expose the `user` attribute **after** actions without explicitly call `model.addAttribute` in every actions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each time you do a `POST`, make a redirection. That way, your `POST` method will only be responsible for updating the data, and the updated data will be loaded by the target controller.

So in this case, the `update()` method would redirect to another controller which would call the `getUser()` method before its `GET` method.

Answer (score 2):

The Post / redirect / GET solution is valid if it works for you.

However, I had a similar situation where I had model attributes that needed to be written by all my controllers, after request processing (tracking information mostly). What I did was to register a custom interface (e.g. `AdditionalModelDataSupplier`), which I apply to all controllers that need to provide additional data. The interface would have a method like this:

```
void provideAdditionalData(Model model, HttpServletRequest request);
```

Now, I wrote an interceptor that in the `postHandle` method checks the Controller bean for this interface and calls this method:

```
@Override
public void postHandle(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Object handler,
        final ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

    AdditionalModelDataSupplier modelDataSupplier = findAdditionalModelDataSupplier(handler);
    if (modelDataSupplier != null) {
        final ModelMap modelMap = modelAndView.getModelMap();
        final Model targetModel;
        if (modelMap instanceof Model) {
            targetModel = (Model) modelMap;
        } else {

            // the modelmap doesn't implement model, so we need to provide a wrapper view
            targetModel = new ForwardingModel(modelMap);
        }

        modelDataSupplier.provideAdditionalData(targetModel, request);
    }
}
@Nullable
private static AdditionalModelDataSupplier findAdditionalModelDataSupplier(final Object handler) {
    if (handler instanceof AdditionalModelDataSupplier) {
        return (AdditionalModelDataSupplier) handler;
    }

    if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
        HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handler;
        Object bean = handlerMethod.getBean();
        if (bean instanceof AdditionalModelDataSupplier) {
            return (AdditionalModelDataSupplier) bean;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

(the `ForwardingModel` class mentioned above is trivial to create, it just delegates everything to the `ModelMap`)